# submitting content to a .txt using php and staying on the same page and not go to the php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I wanna submit/write content to a .txt file and i have to used php to do it, but i don't wanna open the php page and wanna stay on the same page.

How can I do this?

Index.html

```
<form action="writer.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

writer.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "|| \n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo " written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>`
```

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I WANNA WRITE NOT READ!!

Comment: @Azhar ajax is used to send data in both directions...you would write to file based on data sent

Comment: can you show me? @charlietfl

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the web how to submit forms with ajax

Comment: in .php but not in .txt file @charlietfl

Comment: you have to use php to do the writing as well as receive the data

Comment: i can write data in php without using ajax, okay just tell me how to stay on the same page after submission and just show a modal dialog tellin submitted with okay button to close it @charlietfl

Comment: you will know how when you study some ajax form tutorials

Comment: Please don't come here asking for help and then insult those that try to help you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

create a php file with following in it.

```
<?php    
 if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
$input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $input, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}    
  ?>

  <html>
  <body>    
  <form action="" method="post">
<?php if(isset($message)) echo $message; ?>
 <input type="text" name="inputText"/>
 <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't answer your own question of how to stay on same page

Comment: You are asking : "submitting content to a .txt using php and staying on the same page and not go to the php page". Please explain how this will do what you were asking for.

Comment: run it all in a single page and you'll know @Franco

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use iframes, easier alternative to AJAX.

```
<iframe name="panel" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="writer.php" method="POST" target="panel">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

...and as everyone here is yelling, consider learning [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: I was solving your problem for staying on the same page. I thought your script was working, my bad.